# Sharing a network drive between Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, networking, windows, storage, file-format

I am currently installing a Linux distro onto the SSD of a new desktop in my home. This PC will also have a HDD for storage which will be permanently mounted on this Linux OS, but I would also like to set up this HDD so that it can be accessible by all (Windows and Linux) machines across my home through the network.

Is this possible, and if so should I have it formatted as NTFS?

Comment: Personally I would use exFAT as it is supported by Windows natively now, and I believe most/all of the major Linux OSes. Double check to be sure, however

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is possible and you don't have to format it as NTFS, you can export it as a samba share.

You don't give the name of the distro you're using, but there are plenty of guides available for creating a samba share on all the main distros.

Answer (score 0):

As einonm mentioned, you can use samba.  Since you didn't mention your distribution.  Here's a generic primer on mounting and using a samba share in Windows:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client